# Range.Find Method Compile Error with "What" value

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, find

I have the following code that I'm using within an excel spreadsheet, which essentially grabs the last entry of a user's name (saved as x), and then scans upwards through the range to find the last occurrence of that name:

```
For num = 9 To endnum
        Sheets("Financial Reporting").Select
        x = Range("A" & num).Value
        Sheets("Actuals Raw Data").Select
        Set r = Range("E1:E100")
        Set ans = r.Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If ans Is Nothing Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
...
```

The code isn't the most efficient, but at the moment I'm curious as to why I'm getting the compiler error: `Named Argument not found`, highlighting the "What:=" section of the code:

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj0mh.png)

As far as I can see from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find and from other examples online, that is how the "What" should be defined. I've tried replacing x with a string value instead, but since the error is at compile time I don't believe this is where the error is.

Both r and ans are declared as ranges:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim ans As Range
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Your syntax looks fine - what have you declared `ans` and `r` as?

Comment: @Tom I've declared them both as ranges (with what I hope is the right syntax!)
```
Dim r As Range
Dim ans As Range
```

Comment: That's fine then

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: @SJR x contains a name, but I've also tried both setting x to "hi" and also replacing x in the range.Find call with a simple string. Neither of those get past the compile stage. Curiously enough, stripping the code and putting it into another spreadsheet seems to work, so I'm investigating to see where the error might be.

Comment: I've played around with it some, the code seems to run fine if you delete the .value from the x = line. `x = Range("A" & num)` possibly because x expects a cell value by default.

Comment: Pretty sure you working on Mac by the looks of your screenshot? There are problems with the `.Find` function on Mac, one that I know of is the `SearchFormat` one, but not sure about others. Might have to do with the actual variable name which is x. Might it be that it kind of wants to read `What:=xl....` So would `Set ans = r.Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)` work? Just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: You haven't used `x` anywhere else as a procedure name or anything? Have you declared `x`?

Comment: Just seen your other comment, so `x` might be a red herring. Perhaps a mac issue as per JvdV.

Comment: I'd suggest to macro record the manual steps you would do to replicate the `.Find` and make a comparison.

Comment: Everyone - thanks so much for looking into this for me! I know this is going to be frustrating for you... I ended up following much of the steps above, but could not get past the compile error! In a different spreadsheet, everything worked fine, which is when I suspected something very strange (non-code related) might be happening.

As mentioned in the answer below, I literally took the code and pasted it out to sublime before pasting it back in, and now it works. I've no clue why, but I've learnt a lot through this. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody in the future who stumbles across this and is hoping for a solution, I have a bit of strange one for you.

I stripped down the code and used it in a test workbook, hitting no issues whatsoever with the `range.Find()` call.

I gradually built up the code segment by segment, hitting no errors whatsoever, until I had the full script running in the second workbook.

Frustrated, I ended up literally copying all the code, pasting it into Sublime Text, and then copying that and pasting it back into the VBA editor. **The code now works.**

Unfortunately I've no idea *why* that would work - perhaps some strange formatting or other that was cleaned out by sublime? In any case - perhaps this can help someone in the future :) Thanks to those that commented!